# Login on website using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

On [this website](http://kortladdning3.chalmerskonferens.se/), you can enter your student-card-number, and then it will display how much money is left on that card. I want to obtain the information using JSOUP. This is my current code, but it does not work,

```
        String url = "http://kortladdning3.chalmerskonferens.se/CardLoad_Order.aspx";



        Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();

        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36")               
                 //.data("__VIEWSTATE","%2FwEPDwUHNjA4NDA1NQ9kFgQCAw9kFgoCAQ9kFgICAQ8PFgIeBFRleHQFClBUTSBLb3J0bnJkZAICDxYCHgdWaXNpYmxlaGQCAw8WAh8BaGQCBA8WAh8BaGQCBQ8WAh8BaBYCAgEPEGRkFgBkAgUPDxYCHwAFCShkZXNrdG9wKWRkZGzBhwMIv3yxqKnC0C7%2BPlC0PlDG")
                .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", "%2FwEWBAKG7bXPBQLi0uqnCgKF69rWBAK14fOOCgrUt4CBVP4K0VKe0uOPxLSAu26y")
                .data("hiddenIsMobile", "desktop")
                .data("txtCardNumber", "3819276248xxxxxx")
                .data("SavedCardNumber", "")
                .data("btnNext","N%C3%A4sta")
                .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                .get();


        System.out.println(document.html());
```

I dont have much experience so I dont know where to look for the problem. Some thoughts:

- Should I use `.post()` or `.get()`?
- When looking in chrome devoloper tools, the post data is all the data I send with `.data(.., ..)` function. However if a send `__VIEWSTATE` I get an error, why?
- Should I send decrypted or crypted data? (both are presented in chrome devoloper tools).
- Am using the correct URL?

Comment: you should use `post`.see console network tab.http://i.imgur.com/a5NfLWs.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [knowing what header to send to server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32590398/knowing-what-header-to-send-to-server)

Comment: @FastSnail, If I set a correct cardnumber, then I get CardLoad_Order.aspx which has `get`. Does this mean the url should be `String url = "http://kortladdning3.chalmerskonferens.se/Default.aspx";`  instead? Non of it works anyways....

Comment: @lijas you will be redirect to cardload but before that number should be checked .if you inspect elements you can see form `<form name="frmLogin" method="post" action="default.aspx" id="frmLogin">`.you should use `default` page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use both `get` and `post`:
First you have to send `get` request with no parameters to the `URL` - http://kortladdning3.chalmerskonferens.se/Default.aspx. The server replies with some cookies, and two values you'll use later - `__VIEWSTATE` and `__EVENTVALIDATION`. These values vary from request to request, so you can't use hard-coded values like you did.
After extracting these values, send `post` request, with the same fields you do now.
You can look at a very similar procedure here - [Problems submitting a login form with Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871801/problems-submitting-a-login-form-with-jsoup/31877829#31877829)

Comment: Thank you, it works. Quick qustion about security, what keeps from creating a for-loop and trying all card-number combinations? I guess the server has some limitation on how many times one ip cand send a request?

Comment: I'd also guess the server has some security measures, but trying all possible combination (AKA brute force attack) is not very effective - say you can send 10 requests per second. How long it will take to try all the possibilities?